# How do I stop abandoned buildings in the industry

Tags: cities-skylines

[image]

I constantly have abandoned buildings in my industry area in city skylines. I can't bulldoze them faster than they get abandoned. Can someone please help?

Comment: Note that you do not need to bulldoze them. In time, they may become un-abandoned as people move into them.

Comment: Abandoned building will decrease the land value around them, hindering building growth and re-usage of the building.

Answer (score 10):

Judging by the icons above the non abandoned industrial zones your industries have a lack of raw materials.

This can be resolved in two ways:

1. Create more transport connections like ports (cargo) train-stations and roads into the area. This will allow industries to import resources from outside your city.
2. Create Industries that provide certain raw resources like ore or oil. Check out the appropriate map mode to see if your city contains any of these, then build specialized industrial districts on top of those.

Because you have a very large industrial area it could be that resources simply have trouble reaching your zone. In that case it might be better to create multiple smaller industrial areas around the city so trucks have an easier time reaching them.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mod that automatically demolishes abandoned buildings. Just google "Cities Skylines automatic bulldoze".

If you want to know how to keep the buildings used, the main reason they get abandoned is because a lack of (uneducated) workers, or not enough public transport to the industries. In the picture I don't see any buses or passenger train stops in or near the industry zone.

Comment: If this helped, can you please accept the asnwer?

Comment: Hey so I was trying to use the Auto Bulldoze mod, and I just kept getting an error message every time I loaded into a game. Did this happen to you as well or is this a mod compatibility error on m end?

Comment: I never encountered this kind of error. You're better off going to the steam forums of contacting the developer of the mod. What other mods are you using?

Comment: Also, be warned that using this mod disables ironman mode and therefore prevents you from getting achievements.